# How to check the format of keyboard input for a Perl script?

Tags: regex, perl

My Perl script just takes whatever you give as an input, and I want make it more robust by checking the pattern of the input string. My input string has to be in the format `xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx`. How can I check that?

Comment: You could indeed use a regular expression for that. What have you tried? If you're looking for a generic how-to, you may want to try reading the regular expression portion of the intro documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions

Comment: something like? `exit unless $input =~ /^xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx$/;`

Comment: Depending what you're doing with your input, sometimes 'trying to use it' is also quite a good form of validation. E.g. see if a file exists and is readable. etc.

Comment: What have you tried?  And please also show us an actual example of your input.

Comment: Right, what are x's supposed to be? Numbers? Letters? Either? Anything? Is the pattern actually strictly `5characters-4characters-4characters`? These things really matter for how strict the validation can be.

Comment: `my $input; do { chomp( $input = <> ) } while $input ne 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$foo =~ /^.{5}-.{4}-.{4}\z/s
```

For example, this will repeatedly ask for the value until it gets a valid one.

```
my $foo;
while (1) {
   print("Please provide foo (xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx): ");
   my $foo = <STDIN>;
   die("EOF\n") if !defined($foo);
   chomp($foo);
   last if $foo =~ /^.{5}-.{4}-.{4}\z/s;
   print("Invalid input\n");
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to the answer